# gaining access to a secured SwaggerResource

Tags: authentication, swagger, springfox

I have been working my way through this example https://github.com/varghgeorge/microservices-single-swagger , the problem I have encountered is that I know the endpoint of my swagger document but In order to access it directly through my browser I need to provide a username and password. I would like to programmatically do that in order to avoid the following error.

Having provided as configuration, urls complete with prepended access credentials:

```
Errors
Hide
Fetch errorFailed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials: https://username:password@my-host/v2/api-docs https://username:password@my-host/v2/api-docs
Fetch errorPossible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (https://my-host) does not match the page (http://localhost:8080). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it adding a new @Bean in my security configuration to APIs projects

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.setAllowCredentials(false);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);

        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

There is a very similar code proposed in Springfox documentation to enable CORS headers. [See here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#q21).